# how to subtract min of timeseries every interval?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a metric `nomad_raft_appliedIndex` with env, job and instance labels (and also some other labels). The metric is increasing every interval by some value. The increase itself is not important - the difference of increase between instances is important.

What I want to do, is to take minimum every interval and subtract for every instance. So assuming values like (time, instance1, instance2):

```
2022-12-09 11:32:30    1040095    1040095
2022-12-09 11:32:45    1040102    1040100
2022-12-09 11:33:00    1040103    1040106
```

I would want to get:

```
2022-12-09 11:32:30    0 0
2022-12-09 11:32:45    2 0 
2022-12-09 11:33:00    0 3
```

How do I do that? I am fine with any result that will show *relative differences* between values. So `increase` or `rate` but relative to the smallest or highest value in particular interval showed by grafana. I've tried various combinations of operators:

```
nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"} 
# - 
#on (env, job)
#group_left (instance)
#(min by (env) without (instance)
#(bottomk by (env, job)
#(1, nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"}))
```

However none of them are working. Examples:

The following:

```
nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"} 
- on (env, job) group_left (instance) min without(instance) (nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"})
```

Results in:

```
 execution: multiple matches for labels: grouping labels must ensure unique matches
```

The following:

```
nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"} 
- on (env, job)
(bottomk by (env, job)
(1, nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"}))
```

Results in:

```
execution: multiple matches for labels: many-to-one matching must be explicit (group_left/group_right)
```

The following:

```
nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"} 
- (bottomk by (env, job)
(1, nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"}))
```

Results in only one instance with all zeros.

The following:

```
nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"} 
- (min without(instance) (nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"}))
```

Results in "No data" in grafana, which I read it means that "labels do not match".

I tried also sprinkling the code with `[$__interval]` but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combination works:

```
nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"}
- on (env, job) group_left()
(min by(env, job) (nomad_raft_appliedIndex{env="$env",job="nomad"}))
```